# Placing between n and n+2 different books into n different boxes

Tags: combinatorics

The homework question asks:

> There are n (for integers $n>1$) different boxes, each of which can hold up to $n+2$ books. Find the probability that:
>
> a) No box is empty when $n$ different books are put into the boxes at random.
>
> b) Exactly one box is empty when $n$ different books are put into the boxes at random.
>
> c) No box is empty when $n+1$ different books are put into the boxes at random.
>
> d) No box is empty when $n+2$ different books are put into the boxes at random.

My reasoning has led to the following results:

> a. Sample space: $n^n$. 1 per box means $n!$.
>
> $\frac{n!}{n^n} = \frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}$.
>
> b. Sample space also $n^n$. Place first $n-1$ items: $_{}^{n}P_{n-1}$, $n-1$ ways to place last item.
>
> $\frac{(n-1)n!}{n^n}$.
>
> c. Sample space: $n^{n+1}$. Place first $n$ items: $_{}^{n+1}P_{n}$, $n$ ways to put last item.
>
> $\frac{(n+1)!}{n^n}$.
>
> d. Sample space: $n^{n+2}$. Place first $n$ items: $_{}^{n+2}P_{n}$, $n^2$ ways to put last 2 items.
>
> $\frac{n(n+2)!}{2n^{n+1}}$.

The book gives the answers as follows respectively, so I sense that my reasoning on the whole has been incorrect:
$$
\frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}} \\
\frac{(n-1)n!}{2n^{n-1}} \\
\frac{(n+1)!}{2n^n} \\
\frac{(3n+1)(n+2)!}{24n^{n+1}}
$$

I would greatly appreciate any advice or correction as to why my reasoning is incorrect, and how to correctly derive the correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for a) is correct. Coming to b) first you choose the empty box in $n$ ways, then the box to contain $2$ books in $(n-1)$ ways. Further the $2$ books may be chosen in $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ways. And finally the remaining $n-2$ books arranged in $(n-2)!$ ways. Hence required probability $= \frac{n!(n-1)}{2n^{n-1}}$.

c) and d) are similar.

**Update on (d)**

There are $2$ cases here

Case $1$: One box has $3$ books and the rest have $1$ book each. This can be done in $n \times \binom{n+2}{3} \times (n-1)! = \frac{n(n+2)!}{3!}$ ways.

Case $2$: $2$ boxes have $2$ books each and rest have $1$ book each. Choose the $2$ boxes in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways. Now $2$ books can be put in the first box in $\binom{n+2}{2}$ ways. Further, $2$ books in the second box in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways. Remaining books in $(n-2)!$ ways. Hence total $\frac{n(n-1)(n+2)!}{8}$ ways.

Add cases $1$ and $2$ to get the required probability.

Comment: Could you please clarify how it works for d)? I have considered counting the possibilities of 3 in one or 2 in one and 1 in the other, but I'm still not quite getting the answer.

Comment: Hope this helps